MariaDB Is there a syntax to update the values with ONDUPLICATE without having to rewrite all columns
I have to update a existing record e.g.
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    column1 = VALUES(column1),
    column2 = VALUES(column2),
    column3 = VALUES(column3);

but it is a little verbose to set every column on the ON DUPLICATE clause
Is there a syntax to just update all rows if ON DUPLICATE without the need to repeat every columns?
I saw there is a REPLACE keyword but REPLACE is not good it loses index and not very performant.
I'd like something like:
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
    VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
    ON DUPLICATE UPDATEALL

Something like that..

Have you read the reference documentation for MariaDB on INSERT... ON DUPLICATE?

I'm not that senior on Databases, I saw this is not possible with ON DUPLICATE, so I'm asking if there are other keyword or similar. Maybe I'm asking the question on the wrong community I think stackoverflow is being used to post only senior questions by senior developers

@orochi there is no such way of doing DUPLICATE UPDATEALL. But you could use a store procedure . Are you interested on a SP ?

@ErgestBasha yes maybe I could use SP thanks

"REPLACE is not good it loses index and not very performant" don't know what you mean by loses index, and it's very likely to perform well enough for your needs

What version of MariaDB are you using? It might be that INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is faster in older versions and REPLACE might be equally as fast on new ones.

'is there a sintax to just update all rows if ON DUPLICATE without the need to repeat every columns?' - No

@markusjm - Do you know which version made that improvement?  REPLACE used to be defined as DELETE + INSERT.  Note that AUTO_INCREMENT values are lost and re calculated.

@orochi - The column(s) that defines the duplicate key does not need to be listed in the ON DUPLICATE list.  (I realize that this does not address your question.)

@orochi - "it loses index" ==> REPLACE is defined as DELETE + INSERT. Note that AUTO_INCREMENT values are lost and re calculated.
